# opening url succeeds on localhost but fails on production

Tags: php, laravel, curl, sms

I've succeeded in opening a url using "get_file_contents()" php function, curl functions, and guzzlehttp package.

But all the mentioned ways fail when I use the same code on the production server.

"get_file_contents" results this error:

> file_get_contents(https://example.com:xxxx/bulksms/bulksms?username=xxx&password=xxx&type=0&dlr=1&destination=xxx&source=xxx&message=xxx): failed to open stream: Connection refused

while "guzzlehttp" results this error:

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to example.com port xxxx: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

The code for using "get_file_contents":

```
$url = 'http://example.com:xxxx/bulksms/bulksms?username=xxx&password=xxx&type=0&dlr=1&destination=xxx&source=xxx&message=xxx';
return file_get_contents($url);
```

The code for using "guzzlehttp":

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$api_link = 'https://xx.example.com:xxxx/bulksms/bulksms';
$result = $client->get($api_link, [
                'query' => [
                    'username' => 'xxx',
                    'password' => 'xxx',
                    'type' => 0,
                    'dlr' => 1,
                    'destination' => 'xxx',
                    'source' => 'xxx',
                    'message' => 'xxx'
                ]
]);
```

I want to kindly mention again that the same code is working successfully from localhost!

Comment: You may have some firewall or restriction issue on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try that solution to rename your `.env` file.

From .`env.example` to `.env` in your root folder.